# After upgrading to 20.10, the Jetbrains Space desktop app crashes on startup due to a snap Dbus error

Tags: upgrade, snap, dbus, 20.10

Yesterday, I signed up for the Jetbrains Space beta and started setting up projects with the desktop app, which worked normally.

Today, I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10. Now, whenever I try to launch the app  it immediately crashes, and starting it from terminal results in the following error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: cannot set "default-url-scheme-handler" setting to invalid value "jbspace"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to remove and reinstall the package, but the same error still occurs. Googling showed that this probably originates from snap, but I didn't manage to find what exactly it is.

I would imagine this is because some dependency was removed (I also had to reinstall the WiFi driver), but I have no idea which.

What does this error mean? Is there any way I can fix this, or packages I might need to install/upgrade/downgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in on X11 instead of Wayland solves the issue.

Most probably the following issues in snapd/Ubuntu are related

- https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/9530
- https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apps-wont-run-and-crash-on-gnome-wayland/20322/14
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1897224

(see related issue in [Space tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SPACE-11892) for details)